# Error in multi app: Cannot resolve module 'babel-loader' after upgrading babel to v7

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, jestjs

It seems I've got all that is needed installed, but still cannot make it work.

Here's my package.json:

```
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "^23.4.2",
    "babel-loader": "7.1.1",
```

Then, I have a webpack.config.js file for configuring webpack. There's the fragment that causes problems:

```
webpackConfig.module.loaders = [{
  test    : /\.(js|jsx)$/,
  exclude : /node_modules/,
  loader  : 'babel-loader',
  query   : project.compiler_babel
}, {
  test   : /\.json$/,
  loader : 'json'
}];
```

anything I type instead of 'babel-loader' as a value of loader key will be mentioned in the error message in the place of "babel-loader".

And I also have project.config.js where the query leads:

```
compiler_babel : {
    cacheDirectory : true,
    plugins        : ['transform-runtime'],
    presets        : ['es2015', 'react', 'stage-0']
  },
```

I have also tried to work with babel.config.js, with configuration from compiler_babel, but did not get the way with it.

Any ideas how can I make it work? I'm planning to write some test in jest for react application, therefore I need some newer babel packages.

P.S. The precise error message:

> ERROR in multi app Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module
>   'babel-loader' in ...  @
>   multi app

and my webpack version is
"webpack": "^1.15.0",

Comment: isn't it now `@babel/core`?

Comment: changed it to @babel/core, now the error changed:
ERROR in Loader /Users/.../node_modules/@babel/core/lib/index.js?{"cacheDirectory":true,"plugins":["transform-runtime"],"presets":["es2015","react","stage-0"]} didn't return a function
 @ multi app

Comment: Yeah so I use babel loader ^8.0.5 with @babel/core ^7.1.6

Answer (score 1):

Check the [documentation](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader). You need babel-loader v8 with Babel v7.

Comment: Thanks, upgraded to v8 of babel-loader, changed loader to babel-loader, now the error is Cannot find module 'babel-plugin-transform-runtime'

Comment: change `babel-plugin-*` to `@babel/plugin-*`